# Combobox Dependant on Checkbox

Tags: forms, excel, vba, checkbox, combobox

I have been able to change the list (or `RowSource`) of a Combobox dependant on whether an Optionbox has been selected using the following code:

```
Private Sub optYes_Click()
    Options
End Sub

Private Sub optNo_Click()
    Options
End Sub

Private Sub Options()
    Select Case True
        Case optYes.Value = True
            cmb.Enabled = True
            cmb.RowSource = "=Options!A1:A4"
        Case optNo.Value = True
            cmb.Enabled = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

I would like to modify this slightly so that the Combobox list is limited to a group of Checkboxes that have been selected. So if I have 10 checkboxes denoting different options, and the user only selects 4 of them, then only those 4 will appear in the Combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Private Sub Algeria_Change()
    Options
End Sub

Private Sub Bangladesh_Change()
    Options
End Sub

Private Sub Canada_Change()
    Options
End Sub

Private Sub Denmark_Change()
    Options
End Sub

Private Sub Options()
    Dim names As Variant, name As Variant
    Dim old As String

    names = Array("Algeria", "Bangladesh", "Canada", "Denmark")

    old = cmb

    cmb.Clear
    cmb.Enabled = False
    For Each name In names
        If Me.Controls(name) Then
            cmb.AddItem Me.Controls(name).Caption
            cmb.Enabled = True
            If name = old Then cmb.SelText = old
        End If
    Next name
End Sub
```

If you need more checkboxes just add their name to `names` and call `Options` when they change.

Comment: Thanks. The issue with this however is that it in essence chooses the first i cells in column A, irrespective of what values are in those cells. So if 3 checkboxes are selected, the combobox will list the first 3 cells in column A but not necessarily the values that were selected using the checkboxes - so if I selected B and D from A,B,C,D then the combobox will show A and B but not B and D.

Comment: @user2696883 That's exactly what it does: Display the first `i` lines of columns A inside the combobox corresponding to the number of checkbox selected, regardless of their name.

Comment: Thanks, however I would like it to show _those_ exact values have been selected rather than the first i lines corresponding to the number of checkboxes selected. How can I do this?

Comment: @user2696883 I don't understand, did you try the example? What do you mean by "those exact values"? Don't you want to display the content of the cells?

Comment: I did try the example @z. What I mean is that say the checkboxes have the options for Alegria, Bangladesh, Canada and Denmark, and I only select Bangladesh and Denmark, then the combobox should only show these two countries and not Algeria and Bangladesh that would be the first 2 on the list.

Comment: @user2696883 Alright, but before I edit my answer, do you really need to refer to the spreadsheet (with `RowSource`) or is the list supposed to show the exact same values as the checkboxes' name, in which case refering to the cells wouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @Z, no I don't need to refer to the worksheet. I am happy to implement whatever would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @Z - Perfect. This works well and I have accepted your answer. Thanks!